# Custom sort according to substrings

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2013

I want to sort the following list in Excel 2013 by letter and then number.  There are values such as `A-X` which come after numbers.

```
A-1
A-20
A-2
A-X
B-1
B-2
B-20
B-7
B-X
B-9
```

How can I create a custom Sort Filter for this column to produce:

```
A-1
A-2
A-20
A-X
B-1
B-2
B-7
B-9
B-20
B-X
```

Comment: Hopefully this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/813742/alphanumeric-sorting-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

I suggest copying your entire data column into another column in the same spreadsheet and then applying Text to Columns (DATA > Data Tools) on that copy with hyphen `-` as the delimiter. This should split the copy into two columns, based on your example one of text only, the other a mix of numbers and letters. Sort the sheet based on the text only column (A to Z) then by the mixed column (Smallest to Largest):

[image: SO31710925 example]

and then delete the two surplus columns, if no longer required. Excel considers numbers before letters when sorting by "size" though [sort orders vary by locale setting](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654).

The above is assuming your data is just a sample and you wish the same principle applied to say `A-3`, `b-44`, `D-z` etc. However, since you mention  custom Sort Filter it may be that you have several extracts from the data above and want each to be sorted in the given order, e.g. to sort `B-7`, `A-X` and `A-2` (in that order) into order: `A-2`, `A-X` and `B-7` for which a Custom List may be more suitable. For that go to FILE > Options > Advanced > General and click on <kbd>Edit Custom Lists...</kbd>.

Then click on <kbd>Import</kbd>, select the comprehensive list that is in the required order (or type it in under List entries:) and <kbd>Add</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>. Now one of the Order options in the Sort modal should be that list.